# Wrap a div in a url kohana

Tags: php, html, kohana-3

I am using kohana framework.

I am trying wrap a url in a div in other to make the div clickable.
I normally do it like this

```
<a href "www.test.com">
  <div class="foo1>
       <div class="foo2">
       <?php   ?>
       </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

but in this case I am using this framework.

the div I am trying to wrap as other div and those div as php tags

I am trying to wrap this

```
<?php echo HTML::anchor($link .$test1->getid(). '/travel'); ?>
```

any idea how I will wrap this in in a div

or Make `<?php echo HTML::anchor($link .$test1->getid(). '/travel'); ?>`
work on 
jquery `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is the text that will be shown as the title/text inside the a tag, check the documentation for [HTML::anchor](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/HTML#anchor)

Maybe this will work.

```
<?php echo HTML::anchor($link .$test1->getid(). '/travel', <div class="foo1"><div class="foo2">your content</div></div>); ?>
```

Please note that putting divs in anchor tags may not be semantically right.

Comment: Thanks but the example you show didn't work but showed an error.

Comment: Maybe Jquery might be the only way for this.